# Getting the text after a regex match and a negative condition

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I'm practising my regex skills trying to filter the 'token' that's different from `BNB` in a transaction.

**Here is an example:**

The original text :

```
['Sender Receiver Amount Currency',
 '0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e',
 '0x5b9f811d38fc6c1017e0774c552235b33f564deb',
 '1.00 WBNB',
 '0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e',
 '0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c',
 '1.00 BNB',
 '0x5b9f811d38fc6c1017e0774c552235b33f564deb',
 '0x6b1ecb203d82fec24f8b684f7906ef98ec9abf0a',
 '596.32 RBH',
 '0x6b1ecb203d82fec24f8b684f7906ef98ec9abf0a',
 '0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e',
 '1.00 BNB',
 '0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c',
 '0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e',
 '1.00 WBNB']
```

This is the regex I use for the try:

```
'(((?<=\d\w ))\w*[^BNB])'
```

But this is the result I get:

```
[("WBNB'", ''), ("BNB'", ''), ("RBH'", ''), ("BNB'", ''), ("WBNB'", '')]
```

Any idea for a correct way to get what I need?
(in this case only "RBH")

Comment: `[^...]` is negation of character set, that is not matching any character inside the bracket, in this case, it just means to match something not end with `B` or `N`.

Comment: Do the length matter? Should we filter something like `WWBNB` and `ABCBNB`. How about character after `BNB` like `BNBW` and `BNBABC`, and `BNB` in the middle like `WBNBW`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `(((?<=\d\w ))\w*[A-Z]{0,1}[^N][^B](?='))`

Comment: thanks @codographer and also thanks to Eric that also explain a lot with his approach 

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead with a single capture group:

```
\d (?![A-Z]*BNB)([A-Z]+)
```

**Explanation**

- `\d`  Match a digit and a space
- `(?![A-Z]*BNB)` Negative lookahead, assert not optional chars A-Z followed by BNB to the right
- `([A-Z]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ chars A-Z

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5mUCGt/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/kMEd5v)

**Example code**

```
import re

strings = ['Sender Receiver Amount Currency', '0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e', '0x5b9f811d38fc6c1017e0774c552235b33f564deb', '1.00 WBNB', '0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e', '0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c', '1.00 BNB', '0x5b9f811d38fc6c1017e0774c552235b33f564deb', '0x6b1ecb203d82fec24f8b684f7906ef98ec9abf0a', '596.32 RBH', '0x6b1ecb203d82fec24f8b684f7906ef98ec9abf0a', '0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e', '1.00 BNB', '0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c', '0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e', '1.00 WBNB']
pattern = r"\d (?![A-Z]*BNB)([A-Z]+)"

for s in strings:
    m = re.search(pattern, s)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

**Output**

```
['RBH']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for your personal reference, the website [regex101](https://regex101.com/) is an excellent resource to t/s exactly what you're looking for. Here is what I wrote that should extract exactly the text you want:

```
((\d )((?!.BNB)(?!BNB)(?!BNB.))(\w*))
```

Now let's talk for a second about what all this means:

1. \d is looking for a digit at the start of the text
2. ?! excludes all three patterns in the middle (anything that ends with a BNB, starts with a BNB, or is BNB)
3. The end part is just looking for whatever is left

Based on the string you provided. This should pretty well do it to extract the information you were looking for. I tried it on your text, and it grabbed only what I wanted in Group 4. I hope that clears it up!